# ButterCMS: Unknown field on RootQueryType

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Hello Im trying to query data into Gatsby from ButterCMS by following the documentation in gatsby-source-buttercms(https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-buttercms/#gatsby-source-buttercms). But got the error "unknown field allButterJob on RootQueryType". I dont know what i did wrong. Someone please take a look at this for me. Here's my gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-buttercms',
      options: {
        authToken: '2a926fdcab34e736332a54e24649cedbaf5d0e89',
        contentFields: {
          keys: [ // Comma delimited list of content field keys.
            'job',
            'news'
          ],
          test: 0 // Optional. Set to 1 to enable test mode for viewing draft content.
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Here's where i made the query:

```
import React                 from 'react'
import Link                  from 'gatsby-link'
import HeaderlineSection from '../components/headerlineSection'
import FeatureSection    from '../components/featureSection'
import TeamSection         from '../components/teamSection'
import NewsSection         from '../components/newsSection'
import CareerSection     from '../components/careerSection'

const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <div>
    <HeaderlineSection />
    <FeatureSection />
    <TeamSection />
    <NewsSection />
    <CareerSection /> 
    {console.log(data)}
  </div>
)

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery{
    allButterJob{
      edges{
        node{
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

`RootQueryType` is the top level “item” in your GraphQL schema (Gatsby v1 sets this up). So the relevant part of the error here is “unknown field allButterJob”, which is pretty self explanatory: the field/type you're trying to query doesn't exist at the top level.

It's likely that it's there under a different name. Usually I hop into Graphiql (localhost:8000/___graphql if you're running `gatsby develop` under the standard port), where you will see something like this in the sidebar (click on the Docs link if it isn't showing):

[image]

From here you can click on “Query” to drill down into it. (*Note that this screenshot is from a Gatshy v2 app, so instead of `RootQueryType` it's just listed as `Query`.*) That'll pull up a list of the fields available on `Query` (or in your case, `RootQueryType`) that looks something like this:

[image]

In this example, `allSitePage` is a top-level field available to query like this:

```
query AnythingYouLikeHere {
  allSitePage {
    edges {
      node {
        path
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i understand this. But i think there's sth wrong with my configuration file that's why it cant pull data in from Buttercms. Can u look at my configuration for buttercms. See if there's anything wrong.